# Omniauth redirects back to signin page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth, omniauth-google-oauth2

So I'm trying to integrate Google OAuth2 with devise in my app but after signing in and allowing access to the app I get redirected back to the sign in page for some reason. I'm using the following tutorial:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-devise-and-omniauth-for-your-rails-application

Here are my files:

callbacks_controller.rb

```
class CallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def google_oauth2
    # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    if @user.persisted?
      flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Google"
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
    else
      session["devise.google_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end

end
```

route.rb:

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "callbacks" }
```

users.rb:

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
        user.provider = auth.provider
        user.uid = auth.uid
        user.email = auth.info.email
        user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    end
end
```

devise.rb:

```
config.omniauth :google_oauth2, ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'], ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'], callback_url: ENV['GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URL']
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: You check `@user.persisted?` but where you save `@user` ? I think that it is always false

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    # return path you want to go to...
  end
end
```